# set with embeddable, nullable properties

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, set, embeddable

I have `Set<Reference>` with embeddable class in it mapped like this.

```
@ElementCollection
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_object_org_ref")
@CollectionTable(name = "m_object_org_ref", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
public Set<Reference> getParentOrgRef() {
    return parentOrgRef;
}
```

Reference is mapped like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Reference implements Serializable {

    @Column(length = 36, insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)
    public String getTargetOid() {
        return targetOid;
    }

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    public RContainerType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    public String getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    ...other methods/fields...
}
```

When I try to merge parent entity (for example I remove one reference from set), hibernate  generates this sql as prepared statement during merge...

```
delete from reference where object_id=? and object_oid=? and description=? and filter=? and localPart=? and namespace=? and targetOid=? and type=?
```

but if for example description was `NULL` then this delete fails, more exactly it doesn't delete record because where clause is not good (`description=null`, proper way is `description is null`). So how can I tell hiberate that it should create "better" sql delete?

It works only if all fields have non null values.

Comment: If you use Oracle DB, there's no difference between null and empty string. So you can either set your getter to return empty string or use an interceptor. More explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251767/how-do-i-force-hibernate-to-return-an-empty-value-instead-of-null