# How do I force Hibernate to return an empty value instead of null?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Oracle 11GR2 and when the varchar2 field is empty, doing a `System.out.println` on the empty field will display `null` on my Eclipse console. How can I have it display the empty string instead?

Comment: The problem is, in Oracle using varchar2, there is no difference between null and empty string.  Empty string in Oracle using varchar2 in fact means null.  However I believe you can write an interceptor for Hibernate to deal with such case, so that you can "replace" null string with empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your getter method:

```
public String getVarchar2()
{
    if(this.varchar2==null)
        return "";
    else
        return this.varchar2;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that. I was hoping I didn't have to do it from there :P

Answer (score 6):

doing the trick in getter is fine but it kind of change the desired behavior of the model.

As quoted in my comment, Oracle has no way to distinguish between empty string and null. If you are sure that all string attribute you are using will never be null, you may create an interceptor in hibernate like this

```
public class EmptyStringInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean onLoad(Object entity, 
                         Serializable id, 
                         Object[] state, 
                         String[] propertyNames,
                         Type[] types) {
      for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
         if (StringType.equals(types[i]) && state[i] == null) {
               state[i] = "";
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

You may refer to [Hibernate's document for use of interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html)

Answer (score 2):

Interceptor is the way to go, if you want to change the behaviour for all Strings. Oracle internally treats empty string as null (`'' is null` returns true), but this may not hold for other databases. For them, you should override the `onFlushDirty` and `onSave` methods as well to not use `null` in database (or to always use them, if you prefer):

```
public class MPSessionInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, 
            Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        return convertEmptyStrings(currentState, types);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        return convertEmptyStrings(state, types);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, 
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        return convertEmptyStrings(state, types);
    }

    private boolean convertEmptyStrings(Object[] state, Type[] types) {
        // convert nulls to empty strings
        boolean modified = false;
        for (int i=0; i<state.length; i++)
            if ((types[i] instanceof StringType) && state[i] == null) {
                state[i] = "";
                modified = true;
            }
        return modified;
    }

}
```

You may refer to [Hibernate's document for use of interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html)